# There exists an API for dictation recognizer for Android in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, speech-to-text

I need an API to write what I say via microphone in an Android App developed by Unity.
I have searched but all dictation api I see in Unity is for Windows.
There exists an API you know for Android devices that could be use in Unity for this purpose?

Comment: I thought there were a few free/low paid ones on the asseststore

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search on the asset store. [You should check this one out.](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/audio/mobile-speech-recognizer-73036)
I can't tell, if it is a solution for your problem, but i recommend to search the asset store by yourself as well.